# How do you make text which changes in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i am currently making a celsius to Fahrenheit converter gui but I can' figure out how to add text which changes each time a conversion happens. Can any of you help?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
inputValue=0
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x170')
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue =textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    inputValue= int(inputValue)*(9/5)+32
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())

label1=tkinter.Label(root, text=str(inputValue), font=('Calibri', 18, 'bold'))
label1.config()


#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Put `label1.config(text=inputValue)` in `retrieve_input()` instead of `print(inputValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
labelname.config(text = text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Typo error. Remove parameter in `Label1.config`

You are missing widget `pack()`. Replace this:

```
label1.config()
```

to:

```
label1.pack()
```

and add this:

`label1.config(text=inputValue)` in `retrieve_input()`function.

Result before enter input:

[image]

Result after:

[image]